# Omniauth Session NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, hash, omniauth

I am working on a rails app that allows users to log in via facebook/twitter/linkedin using omniauth. So far, users are able to sign up and create an account using the authentications, but they must pass validations and are therefore forwarded to a signup page where they must enter a valid name, username, and email. I want these fields to be already filled out if possible using the request.env["omniauth.auth"] hash.

Here is my code:

authentications_controller.rb

```
user = User.new 
user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)

if user.save
  flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
  sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
else 
  session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
  redirect_to new_user_registration_url
end
```

registrations_controller.rb:

```
def build_resource(*args)
  super
  if session[:omniauth]
    @user.apply_omniauth(session[:omniauth])
    @user.valid?
  end
 end
```

user.rb:

```
def apply_omniauth(omniauth)
  self.name = omniauth['user_info']['name'] if name.blank?
  self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email'] if email.blank?
  authentications.build(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
end
```

The line:

```
self.email = omniauth['user_info']['email'] if email.blank?
```

results in this NoMethodError:

```
undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass
```

The session[:omniauth] is being passed from the registrations controller to omniauth in the apply_omniauth  method. How do I access the name and email in this session?

Thanks

Comment: When they released omniauth 1.0, they changed the auth['user_info'] to just auth['info'] - A handy piece of info to know if you are upgrading gem versions...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Quick answer:

   ```
   omniauth.info.email # which is the same as omniauth['info']['email']
   ```
2. Explanatory answer:

   Put this as the first line of your callback controller:

   ```
   render :text => "<pre>" + env["omniauth.auth"].to_yaml and return
   ```

   Now try to login and you'll be able to take a good look at the hash of nested hashes returned.

Comment: Thanks first ! For the explanatory answer, where should we add that line of code ?

Comment: Surely you have a `SessionsController` or `AuthenticationsController` that receives the callback from facebook or twitter or what have you. Generally, the action that is called is the `create` action, right? All you have to do is put that line of code at the beginning of the `create` action.

Comment: When I added that code in the beginning of the create method of AuthenticationsController, I had "RuntimeError in AuthenticationsController#create" :/

Comment: Yes, that's the point. The purpose of raise is to create an error. In this case, create an error with the contents of the request.

Comment: I know it sound a little bit stupid but after deleting the raise thing and adding quick answer again I started to have "undefined method `serialize_into_session' for Symbol:Class". Is it sth related to that ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you are using an old tutorial. Follow this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11097308/1160916

Comment: Yes, I was following the old one, but the thing is even though I switched back to old code, it doesn't work now. Is there anyways to rollback ?