# Devise, Omniauth and Facebook integration session error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, omniauth

I am new to Rails and am installing my first app that integrates Facebook sign in / sign up.  I followed Ryan Bates' RailsCast videos that were posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4954443/1302333.

I followed his tutorial for integrating Twitter and that works, but I'm having issues with Facebook.  When I visit `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook` I receive this error:

```
NoMethodError in AuthenticationsController#create
undefined method `serialize_into_session' for Symbol:Class
```

Here is the full trace:

```
devise (2.1.0) lib/devise/rails/warden_compat.rb:19:in `serialize'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/session_serializer.rb:25:in `store'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/proxy.rb:161:in `set_user'
devise (2.1.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:124:in `sign_in'
devise (2.1.0) lib/devise/controllers/helpers.rb:236:in `sign_in_and_redirect'
app/controllers/authentications_controller.rb:11:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:18:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:414:in `_run__1508312784814672110__process_action__3616665370535505566__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:17:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:123:in `instrument'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:206:in `process_action'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:121:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:45:in `process'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:203:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:14:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:246:in `block in action'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:36:in `call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:68:in `block in call'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `each'
journey (1.0.3) lib/journey/router.rb:56:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:600:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:392:in `call_app!'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:354:in `callback_phase'
omniauth-oauth2 (1.0.2) lib/omniauth/strategies/oauth2.rb:65:in `callback_phase'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:219:in `callback_call'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:175:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:177:in `call!'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/strategy.rb:157:in `call'
omniauth (1.1.0) lib/omniauth/builder.rb:48:in `call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.1.1) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/best_standards_support.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/head.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:21:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:242:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:205:in `context'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:200:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:338:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:64:in `call'
activerecord (3.2.6) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:473:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__2824763875952710462__call__1302249347533121180__callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.2.6) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.2.6) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:62:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
railties (3.2.6) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
/Users/felixthea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
/Users/felixthea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/felixthea/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p136/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'
```

And the authentications_controller.rb file:

```
class AuthenticationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @authentications = current_user.authentications if current_user
  end

  def create
    omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
    authentication = Authentication.find_by_provider_and_uid(omniauth['provider'], omniauth['uid'])
    if authentication
      flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
      sign_in_and_redirect(:user, authentication.user)
    elsif current_user
      current_user.authentications.create!(:provider => omniauth['provider'], :uid => omniauth['uid'])
      flash[:notice] = "Authentication successful."
      redirect_to authentications_url
    else
      user = User.new
      user.apply_omniauth(omniauth)
      if user.save
        flash[:notice] = "Signed in successfully."
        sign_in_and_redirect(:user, user)
      else
        session[:omniauth] = omniauth.except('extra')
        redirect_to new_user_registration_url
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @authentication = current_user.authentications.find(params[:id])
    @authentication.destroy
    redirect_to authentications_url, :notice => "Successfully destroyed authentication."
  end

protected

# This is necessary since Rails 3.0.4
# See https://github.com/intridea/omniauth/issues/185
# and http://www.arailsdemo.com/posts/44
def handle_unverified_request
 true
end

end
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks
Felix

Answer (score 9):

You are using old tutorial version.

If you are using devise 2.0 or higher the steps are:

**1º** in your `config/initializers/devise.rb`

```
require "omniauth-facebook"
config.omniauth :facebook, "YOUR_APP_ID", "YOUR_APP_SECRET", :strategy_class => OmniAuth::Strategies::Facebook
```

**2º** You must install this gems:

```
gem 'omniauth'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'oauth2'
```

**3º** in you `user.rb` model add module `:omniauthable` sth like:

```
class User
 # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
 # :token_authenticatable, :encryptable, :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :omniauthable and :invitable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :omniauthable
end
```

**4º** in your `routes.rb`

```
devise_for :users,  :controllers => { :omniauth_callbacks => "users/omniauth_callbacks", :registrations => "registrations" } do
```

**5º** Create a folder `users` inside your controllers folder and after you must create a file in `app/controllers/users/omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

In this `omniauth_callbacks_controller.rb`

```
class Users::OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def facebook

     # with this code you can see the data sent by facebook
     omniauth = request.env["omniauth.auth"] 

    @user = User.find_for_facebook_oauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"], current_user)

    if @user.persisted?
      flash[:notice] = I18n.t "devise.omniauth_callbacks.success", :kind => "Facebook"
      sign_in_and_redirect @user, :event => :authentication
    else
      session["devise.facebook_data"] = request.env["omniauth.auth"]
      redirect_to new_user_registration_url
    end
   end
end
```

**6º** In your **user.rb** model add to the end this two methods:

```
def self.find_for_facebook_oauth(auth, signed_in_resource=nil)
  user = User.where(:provider => auth.provider, :uid => auth.uid).first
  unless user
    user = User.create(name:auth.extra.raw_info.name,
                         provider:auth.provider,
                         uid:auth.uid,
                         email:auth.info.email,
                         password:Devise.friendly_token[0,20]
                         )
  end
  user
end

def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    super.tap do |user|
      if data = session["devise.facebook_data"] && session["devise.facebook_data"]["extra"]["user_hash"]
        user.email = data["email"]
      end
    end
  end
```

**7º** Last you must add a link to connect with facebook:

In your `devise/registrations/new.html.erb` you must add:

```
<%= link_to "Sign in with Facebook", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:facebook) %>
```

that's all. I hope that it will help! Regards

Comment: Thanks for your help, hyperrjas.  I followed your instructions and am now getting this error.  Any thoughts?  `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in Users::OmniauthCallbacksController#facebook
SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: users.provider: SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."provider" = 'facebook' AND "users"."uid" = '929272' LIMIT 1`

Comment: I can not see your code but the error say that you have not the user provider column in your database. Add provider column to your databasse with `rake db:migrate` command and after check again. if you keep problems you must install a new rails project. You can follow this guide: http://railsapps.github.com/tutorial-rails-devise-rspec-cucumber.html and after follow this steps for facebook connect in your project. Regards!

Comment: What should we do for the twitter as well ?

Comment: undefined method `user_omniauth_authorize_path' for #<#<Class:0x5053c38>:0x5062140>