# Login with Facebook with authlogic and omniauth-facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have user_session_controller. Here i have used authlogic gem and 'omniauth-facebook' gem. and i want that user can login with facebook in my site. I am totally new. Please guide me how to modify this code for login with facebook.

```
def create
    @user_session = UserSession.new(params[:user_session],true)
    if @user_session.save
        flash[:notice] = "Login successful!"
        unless cookies[:last_visited].nil?
            set_last_visited
        end

        cookies.permanent[:last_visited] = Time.now
        if params[:remember_me]
            user = @user_session.user
        user.update_attributes(:remember_token => create_remember_token)
            cookies[:remember_token] = { :value => user.remember_token, :expires => 24.weeks.from_now }
        end
        redirect_back_or_default users_url(@current_user)
    else
        flash[:error]="invalid login and password"
        render :action => :new
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look to my response on:

[Devise, Omniauth and Facebook integration session error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11093120/devise-omniauth-and-facebook-integration-session-error/11097308#11097308)

You can find more tutorial on:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/OmniAuth:-Overview